# Powershell how to triger powershel command on Create New Element, or Edit Element

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Hello I want to ask a question, how to triger powershell command on Creation new element, or edit new element ?

If I add a element to the list I want to fire one command of powershell.

if I edit a element of list i want to fire another powershell command.

How could I triger this functionality ?

Comment: can provide some details/context as to what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: If I adding a element to the list, I want to fire a powershell command. If I edit a listI want to fire another command of powershell.

Comment: i meant what will the powershell do ?  Cant you try workflows on the item added/updated event ?

Comment: But workflow can block on fire. Powershell should update manager permissions of element One tame on a night, and triger all time when items edit or items added to the list.